# Getting error after declaration of a function "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python-3.x

I have written this code and got an error

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
def get_proxies():
   url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
response = requests.get(url)
parser = fromstring(response.text)
proxies = set()
for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
    if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
#Grabbing IP and corresponding PORT
    proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
proxies.add(proxy)
    return proxies
```

And the Error is

```
  File "check.py", line 13
    return proxies
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Unable to understand the error but maybe the line spacing has something to do with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have poor indentation.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

def get_proxies():
    url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    proxies = set()
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
        if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
            #Grabbing IP and corresponding PORT
            proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
            proxies.add(proxy)
    return proxies
```

Comment: Thanks for that
But still getting a different error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lxml.html import fromstring
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'`

Comment: You have to install 'lxml'. You can do that by: `pip install lxml`

Comment: If I solved your problem, pleave accept this answer.

Comment: Indeed, he need to install lxml package. upvote his answer and if you have problem with installation tell us.

Answer (score 1):

Python is senstive to tabs and you forget to import `requests` package:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

def get_proxies():
    url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    proxies = set()
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
        if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
        #Grabbing IP and corresponding PORT
            proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
            proxies.add(proxy)
    return proxies
```

Comment: I did import the requests package it's just I forget to write it here (Copy Paste Mistake)

Comment: Cool. If you had other issues tall us.